# Problem finding the number of r-element multi-subsets of the multi-set $M=\{ a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n},m.b \} $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let $m,n,r \in \mathbb{N}$. Find the number of $r$-element multi-subsets of the multi-set 
$$M= \{ a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n},m.b \} $$

when $r \leq m,r\leq n$.

Below is the given answer.

$\sum_{i=0}^{r} \binom{n}{i}$

My thoughts:

1) $M$ has (n+1) distinct elements.

2) Use this forumula : $H_{r}^{n} = \binom{r+n-1}{r}$

I'm not sure how to get the answers and why there would be 3 answers for the 3 different conditions.

EDIT:

1) Still haven't received any response. Anyone?

Comment: You are probably not getting answers because you are asking 3 questions at a time.  You should consider editing your question down to just one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ and consider the cases 1) $r\le n, r\le m,\;\;$ 2) $n\le r\le m,\;\;$ 3) $m\le r\le n$.

In each case, we can choose $i$ elements from $S$ and $r-i$ $b's$, where $i\le r$ and  $i\le n$ and $r-i\le m$.

1) In case 1, $0\le i\le r$ and there are $\binom{n}{i}$ ways to choose $i$ elements from S, so

$\;\;\;$there are $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{r}\binom{n}{i}$ multisets.

2) In case 2, $0\le i\le n$ so there are $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}=2^n$ multisets.

$\;\;\;$ (In this case, we can choose any subset of $S$, and $S$ has $2^n$ subsets.)

3) In case 3, $i\le r$ and $r-i\le m\implies r-m\le i\le r$,

$\;\;\;$so there are $\displaystyle\sum_{i=r-m}^{r}\binom{n}{i}$ multisets.

Comment: I'm still slightly unclear on why there is a need to split it into 2 seperate sets? Thanks!

Comment: Is it correct that the total number of distinct elements is (n+1) elements?

Comment: We're splitting it into 2 separate sets because the $a_i$ are distinct, while the $b's$ are identical.  Your answer would be correct if we were counting the number of r-element multi-subsets of $\{r\cdot a_1,\cdots ,r\cdot a_n\}$.  The total number of distinct elements in the original multiset is $n+1$, as you say.