# Proving $ \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{r+1} \binom{n}{r} = \frac{1}{n+1} (2^{n+1} - 1) $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm stuck at proving the following.

$$ \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{r+1} \binom{n}{r} = \frac{1}{n+1} (2^{n+1} - 1) $$

This is what I have so far.

$ \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{r+1} \binom{n}{r} = (1) \binom{n}{0} + \frac{1}{2} \binom{n}{0} + \frac{1}{3} \binom{n}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{n}{n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sice we have
$$\frac{1}{r+1}\binom{n}{r}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{r+1},$$
we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{r+1}\binom{n}{r}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{r+1}\\&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{r}-1\right)\\&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(2^{n+1}-1\right).\end{align}$$

Here, note that
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{r}\cdot 1^{n+1-r}\cdot 1^r=(1+1)^{n+1}=2^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very clear. I would just like to know for $\frac{1}{r+1}\binom{n}{r}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{r+1}$, how do you remember the identity? Is it advisable to remember it through combinatorial proof? Just thought any advice would help me memorize it for my exams.

Comment: I guess it's pretty easy to memorize but applying it is where I get stuck sometimes, I think I just need more practice.. :)

Comment: @Faizal: You are welcome. Actually, I don't remember it. I thought that it should have another form such that $r$ is inside and $n$ is outside because $n-r=(n+1)-(r+1)$ etc...

Comment: Ah I see. I have a problem with this too. Maybe you can give some hints? :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941578/problem-finding-the-number-of-r-element-multi-subsets-of-the-multi-set-m-a

Answer (score 3):

**A start:**  Let $f(t)=(1+t)^n=\sum_0^n \binom{n}{r}t^r$.  Calculate $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$ in two different ways.